# after windows 10 upgrade, display on 2nd monitor is blackened

Tags: windows, upgrade

imagery on 2nd monitor is as per this at[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfKDm.png)

I've patched all drivers (laptop is Dell M6800), and re-installed twice, nothing changes. The display on the primary monitor is perfect.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic for SO, I'd say it belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying Device Manager to Roll back to previously installed video & monitor drivers. I had the same problem when I up

Comment: thank you. have tried both, and got to point of a new driver downloaded, though the problem is back.